# Using ImagePicker for two images in same view

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't understand why including two Image picker widgets in the same view is causing my app to crash. I can pick one image but when trying to pick the second, the app crashes without any error messages.

So I basically need to add two images when submitting a form. One image for logo and another for background image.

Image picker plugin:

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

I have them defined like this:

```
File _venueLogo;
File _venueImage;

final _pickers = [ImagePicker(), ImagePicker()];
```

And the methods to set the two images

```
_setVenueImage(img) {
  setState(() {
    _venueImage = img;
  });
}

_setVenueLogo(img) {
  setState(() {
    _venueLogo = img;
  });
}
```

Then in the body I use two ListTiles one for venue image and one for logo image. I'm only posting one here.

```
ListTile(
      subtitle: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: ImagePickerWidget(
          setImage: _setVenueImage,
          picker: _pickers[0],
        ),
      ),
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text("Pick image"),
      ),
    ),
```

This is the image picker method in the `ImagePickerWidget`

```
Future _getImage() async {
  final pickedFile =
      await widget.picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    widget.setImage(File(pickedFile.path));
  } else {
    print('No image selected.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `image_picker` use `multi_image_picker` to have multiple choice of files.

In your `pubspec.yaml` after `dependencies:` add this:

```
  multi_image_picker: ^4.8.0
```